# How to get refresh tokens on Facebook using Python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am currently using the following code for accessing the refresh tokens. Bare in mind that the `config` variable is frequently updated with the new access_token value after it is set.

```
refresh_token_url = config['facebook']['domain'] + \
                    'oauth/access_token?' + \
                    'grant_type=fb_exchange_token&' + \
                    'client_id=' + config['facebook']['client_id'] + '&' + \
                    'client_secret=' + config['facebook']['client_secret'] + '&' + \
                    'fb_exchange_token=' + config['facebook']['access_token']
new_access_token_obj = requests.get(refresh_token_url)
config['facebook']['access_token'] = json.loads(new_access_token_obj.text)['access_token']
```

But that I have noticed is that the `new_access_token_obj` has an expiry time that is lower than the old `access_token` but the two access tokens are different.

So, I am hoping that someone could tell me how to fix this code with a new access token which has a higher `['expires_in']` field.

**PS :** 
Please note that I am aware that long lived tokens can be obtained using a web-app but I am looking to get it through a script (through some work-around).

Comment: So you are trying to generate a new long-lived token from an already extended one? That is not the way it works, you need to get a fresh short-lived token first, and then get a new extended one using that. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension#refreshtokens

Comment: I was hoping to get long-lived tokens using a script through somework-around using localhost (If that's possible)

Comment: No, that is not possible. You need a new short-lived user token first, and that means you need to send the user through the login flow.